# Tricky pointer question

Tags: c, pointers

I'm having trouble with a past exam question on pointers in c which I found from this link,
http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/teaching/exams/pastpapers/y2007p3q4.pdf

The question is this:

> A C programmer is working with a
>   little-endian machine with 8 bits in a
>   byte and 4 bytes in a word. The
>   compiler supports unaligned access and
>   uses 1, 2 and 4 bytes to store char,
>   short and int respectively. The
>   programmer writes the following
>   deﬁnitions (below right) to access
>   values in main memory (below left):

Address Byte offset
---------0  --1--  2--  3
0x04 | 10 00 00 00
0x08 | 61 72 62 33
0x0c | 33 00 00 00
0x10 | 78 0c 00 00
0x14 | 08 00 00 00
0x18 | 01 00 4c 03
0x1c | 18 00 00 00

```
int **i=(int **)0x04;  
short **pps=(short **)0x1c;  

struct i2c {  
int i;  
char *c;  
}*p=(struct i2c*)0x10;
```

(a) Write down the values for the following C expressions:

```
**i  
p->c[2]  
&(*pps)[1]  
++p->i
```

I get

```
**i == 0xc78  
p->c[2] == '62'  
++p->i == 0x1000000
```

I don't understand the third question (`&(*pps)[1]`), could someone please explain what is going on here? I understand the pps pointer has been dereferenced but then the address of operator has been applied to the value. Isn't that just like asking for the adress of a constant, for example if I did this

```
int i = 7;  
int *p = &i;
&(*p)   //would this mean address of 7??
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Why the hell do they ask these things instead of teaching useful, clean programming?

Comment: I'm glad someone else thinks so too. I would also just like to thank everyone for their effort in giving quick concise answers. It is much clearer to me know.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `[]` operator takes precedence over the `&` operator. So the code is dereferencing `pps` to get to the first element of an array of `short*`. Since this element is also a pointer, we may treat it as an array and look up the element one position to the right of what it points to, wth `[1]`. Finally, we take the address of that element.

It might be useful to note that `&p[i]` is the same as `p + i` - it gives you a pointer to the element `i` positions to the right of where `p` points to.

The intermediate values are:

```
pps == 0x1c
*pps == 0x18
&(*pps)[1] == *pps + 1 == 0x1A
```

(the `+1` adds two bytes, since it is used on a `short*`)

Comment: Could the person who downvoted me please point out my error(s) so that I can correct it/them?

Comment: +1 for about 20 minutes I thought you were totally wrong (though didn't downvote anyway) but your values seem fine to me

Comment: +1 Thanks for this, I always forget about the order of precedence and end up trying to evaluate things from left to right.

Comment: @ricola86: In that case, let me recommend a thorough reading of the [C++ operator precedence chart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Operator_precedence) :-)

Comment: @MByD: To be fair, for about five minutes, the last number was `0x20` instead of `0x1A`, so I _was_ wrong at some point :-)

Comment: @Aasmund Eldhuset: Thanks for that, I'll have a look.

Answer (score 1):

The expression is parsed as `&((*pps)[1])`; `pps` is being treated as a pointer to an array, you're accessing the first element of that pointed-to array, and then taking the address of that element.

Answer (score 1):

`pps` is a pointer to pointer to short,

which means that `*pps` is a pointer to short (or array of shorts),

`(*pps)[1]` is just like `*(*pps + 1)` [pointers arithmetic],

and `&(*(*pps + 1))` is the address of `*(*pps+1)`,

or, in other words - `(*pps+1)` (which is a pointer to short).

Answer (score 0):

pps is a pointer to a pointer.
It is dereferencing pps. So now you have a pointer. As arrays are just pointers you are then using pps as an array.

It is then same as:

```
short ps[2] = {0x0001,0x034c};
short **pps = &ps;
```

so the result is: 0x034c

Comment: No: `(*pps)[1]` is 0x034c.  `&(*pps)[1]` is 0x1a.

Comment: Yes, your right the pointer address is 0x1a. (comprehension skills lacking at 23:30) :)