# c pointers and memory representation

Tags: c, pointers

I came across this question on SO:
([Tricky pointer question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5465912/tricky-pointer-question)):

A C programmer is working with a little-endian machine with 8 bits in a byte and 4 bytes 
in a word. The compiler supports unaligned access and uses 1, 2 and 4 bytes to store char, short and int respectively. The programmer writes the following deﬁnitions (below right) to access values in main memory (below left):

```
Address | Byte offset

--------|-0--1--2--3----

   0x04 | 10 00 00 00

   0x08 | 61 72 62 33

   0x0c | 33 00 00 00

   0x10 | 78 0c 00 00

   0x14 | 08 00 00 00

   0x18 | 01 00 4c 03

   0x1c | 18 00 00 00
```

```c
int **i=(int **)0x04;  
short **pps=(short **)0x1c;  

struct i2c {  
int i;  
char *c;  
}*p=(struct i2c*)0x10;
```

(a) Write down the values for the following C expressions:

```
**i  
p->c[2]  
&(*pps)[1]  
++p->i
```

That question only answers the third subquestion but I was wondering how the rest of the subquestions would be solved. I'm new to C and trying to improve my understanding on pointers and this was particularly confusing. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Work through them step-by-step. Is there something specific you don't understand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll probably want to refer to this: [Operators in C and C++ - Operator precedence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Operator_precedence)

The question didn't specify, but we will assume that pointers are 4 bytes - `sizeof(void*) == 4`.

---

### 1.

```
int **i=(int **)0x04;
**i = ???
```

`i` is a pointer to a (pointer to `int`). When we say `**i`, we are de-referencing the pointer twice - or reading the value that the pointer points to.

First note that `**i == *(*i)`. So we first read a pointer-sized (4-byte) value from memory at address 0x04. This is `10 00 00 00` - interpreted as a little-endian value, that is 0x10. So now we are left with `*((int*)0x10)`. That means we read an `int`-sized (4-byte) value from memory at address 0x10. `78 0c 00 00` interpretted in little-endian is the value 0xC78.

---

### 2.

```
struct i2c {  
    int i;  
    char *c;  
} *p = (struct i2c*)0x10;

p->c[2] = ???
```

This one's a little trickier. I'll assume that you understand that structures are just a collection of variables that (excluding padding, which doesn't apply here) are laid out one after another in memory.

Our pointer `p` points to a `struct i2c` object at 0x10 in memory. That means at address 0x10 is the `int`, named `p->i`. And immediately following that, at address 0x14, is the `char *`, named `p->c`.

The expression `p->c[2]` means: "First get the `char *c` from the structure that `p` points to. Then, get the `char` at index 2 from the array that `p->c` points to."

So first, we'll get `p->c`. I already mentioned this `char*` is at address 0x14. There we find the pointer `08 00 00 00`, or 0x8.

Now, we have a `char *` that points to address 0x8, and we want the `char` at index 2 in that array.  To get the address of an array element, we use this formula:

```
&(x[y])  ==  (char*)x + (y * sizeof(x[0]))
```

In other words, the offset (from the start of the array) of the `n`th element in the array is `n` times the size of each element.

Since `char`s are 1 byte, `p->c[2]` is at `0x8 + 2 = 0xA`. There we find the value `0x62`, which is the ASCII character `'b'`.

---

### 3.

```
short **pps=(short **)0x1c;

&(*pps)[1] = ???
```

With our knowledge operator precedence, we read `&(*pps)[1]` as "First dereference `pps`, which is a pointer-to-short (or an array of shorts). Then, we want the *address of* the element at index 1."

At address 0x1C we have `18 00 00 00`, or 0x18. So now we have a pointer to an array of shorts, and this array starts at address 0x18.  Using our formula from above, and knowing that `short`s are 2 bytes in size, we calculate element 1 to be at address `0x18 + (1 * 2) == 0x1A`.

At address 0x1A is `4c 03`, or 0x034C.  However, the problem wasn't asking us for the value  of element 1 - that would be solving `(*pps)[1]`. Instead, it asked for `&(*pps)[1]` or the *address of* that element. So, we simply go back to the end of the previous paragraph, where we said the address was 0x1A.

---

### 4.

```
++p->i = ??
```

For this one, you *really* need to know the operator precedence. It should be clear that this could be interpreted two different ways:

- **a)** Increment the pointer `p` <sup>1</sup>, and then dereference `p` to get its member `i`
- **b)** Dereference `p` to get its member `i`, then increment the integer value

From the [precedence chart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Operator_precedence), we see that `->` has a precedence of 2, while `++` (the *Prefix* increment), has a lower precedence of 3. That means we need to apply the `->` first, then increment. Thus, option **b)** was correct.

So, first let's get `p->i`. We already said in part **2.** that since `p` points to address 0x10, and `i` is the first member in `struct i2c`, `p->i` is at address 0x10. There we find `78 0c 00 00`, or 0xC78.

Finally, we need to apply the `++` operator, and increment that value to 0xC79.

.....

<sub>1 - Pointer arithmetic means you treat a pointer like an array. So `p + 3` doesn't mean "`p` plus 3 bytes", it means `&p[3]`, or "`p` plus (3 * sizeof(*p)) bytes".</sub>